# Why is the referenced workbook opening twice, if the command Application.run is not suppposed to be able to open a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro from a different workbook, so at the start I make sure to check if that workbook is open, and to open it if not, but when the program gets to accessing the macro it reopens the workbook, so I end up having it open twice! 
Why is that happening and how can I avoid it, see my code below for reference.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Thisbook As Workbook
Dim Shev As Application
    If IsWBOpen("ShevgenII") Then GoTo Checkup Else  'this step runs a function that checks the names of all open workbooks
        Set Thisbook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set Shev = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="file:///\\FPSFILES1\ReviewPricing\Macro Data\ShevgenII.xlsb", ReadOnly:=True).NewWindow
        Shev.Visible = False
        Thisbook.Activate

Checkup:
    Application.Run "ShevgenII.xlsb!Updates"
End Sub
```

Comment: The presence of `Activate` member calls and `ActiveWorkbook` is worrying. If `IsWBOpen` returns `True`, you're assuming that it's also the active workbook, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: So you think removing that might help? I usually have a LOT of excel docs open at once, and if I dont specify which workbook I want to end up in then I will end up somewhere random (based on passed expereince)....

Comment: No, I'm literally saying the complete opposite: the `ActiveWorkbook` could literally be any random workbook, and your code is assuming that "ShevgenII" is *active* when all the code knows is that it's *opened*. Or is `IsWBOpen` actually `IsWBActive`?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should move ```Set Thisbook = ActiveWorkbook``` before ```IsWBOpen```, I want ```Thisbook``` to be the one I just opened, and I actually want "ShevgenII" to be hidden

Comment: The code is in a workbook.open handler, presumably in the `ThisWorkbook` module; the active workbook would be `ThisWorkbook` then (i.e. the host document), which makes both `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisBook` redundant and confusing layers of indirection: if you mean to work with the host document, use `ThisWorkbook`, and don't copy that pointer to another variable - "ThisWorkbook" means the same thing across the entire code and regardless of which workbook is active.

Comment: Have you tried running the `Application.Run` instruction just all by itself in the immediate pane to see if it works as you expect? Stepping through the code (f9 toggle breakpoint, f8 step-through) to see if execution branches as expected? The real problem could be in the `IsWbOpen` function.

Comment: I tried that now, the trouble seems to start actually with ```Set Shev = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="file:///\\FPSFILES1\ReviewPricing\Macro Data\ShevgenII.xlsb", ReadOnly:=True).NewWindow``` this is where I all of a sudden have two  "ShevgenII" open workbooks

Comment: ```Application.run``` tells me that it can't find the workbook if it hasnt been opened yet

Comment: You don't have two open workbooks, you have two *windows* with the same workbook. If you don't want that `.NewWindow` then declare `Shev As Workbook` and remove the `.NewWindow` chained member call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear why `Shev` is an `Application` object, I'd expect a *type mismatch* error here (you're assigning it to a `Window` reference):

> ```
> Dim Shev As Application
> Set Shev = Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly:=True).NewWindow
> Shev.Visible = False
> ```

Try this instead:

```
Dim Shev As Workbook
Set Shev = Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly:=True)
Shev.Windows(1).Visible = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Write "Exit Sub" before the Label "Checkup"..

Comment: then how exactly will the next line of code get executed? I need that regardless if the workbook had been opened already